# Darboux atlas on a symplectic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Is every finite dimension symplectic manifold admit 'Darboux atlas'.   If not can we have counterexample..

Comment: Dear @Junu could you make precise the meaning of "Darboux atlas"? It could help you to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment, but I am not able to post it.

If by Darboux atlas you mean an atlas on your symplectic manifold such that each open set of this atlas is a Darboux chart (the symplectic form looks like $\sum_j\mathrm{d}x_j\wedge\mathrm{d}y_j$), then the answer to your question is yes (that is why this is named after Darboux).

If by Darboux atlas you mean a global diffeomorphism that sends the symplectic form to a Darboux form, then the answer to your question is no: any compact orientable surface with its area form are symplectic manifolds, and the area form is not exact (exactness is preserved by diffeomorphisms).